# Not recognised the import of media type

Tags: java, restful-architecture

I m trying to make a RESTful web services, i have added the following jar files but when I add the `import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;` It is underlined with red line and it says that
the `"import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;"` collides with another statement. I have tried to organize my imports with ctrl+shift+O and it automatically removes the above import.
The result is that the MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN is not recognized.

[image]

Comment: as you can see in your code, you are importing 1 classes with the same name. how do you expect the compiler to know which is which when you refer to either one of them?

Comment: I think the jersey-server jar has the implementation for MediaType and any javax.ws.rs classes you need so I would remove that javax.ws.rs-api jar.

Answer (score 4):

Import statements are there as a convenience so that you don't have to fully qualify all of your types while writing your code.

If you were allowed to import both classes the compiler wouldn't know which one you meant when you tried to use one or the other.

In the case of a name collision like this, you need to fully qualify one of the types so the compiler has a way of telling `java.awt.PageAttributes.MediaType` apart from `javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType`:

```
import java.awt.PageAttributes.MediaType;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
//import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType; // don't need this anymore

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {
    @GET
    @Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) // fully qualify MediaType
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Technique bro.

Answer (score 1):

You have imported it twice. For the core MediaType you need to import import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  and for Page Attributes you have to import import java.awt.PageAttributes.MediaType;

Choose the right one according to your requirement.